Editar estilo de gráfico usando React Native Chart Kit
Estoy realizando una aplicación usando React Native con la librería de react-native-chart-kit donde actualmente tengo este resultado:

Donde lo que busco tener como resultado final es removerle el relleno del gráfico y hacer el color de la línea un poco mas con 'brillo' ya que parece que tiene un 'opacity'.
Como resultado esperaría algo así:

Este es el código actual que tengo realizado:
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Dimensions, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {
    LineChart,
    BarChart,
    PieChart,
    ProgressChart,
    ContributionGraph,
    StackedBarChart
  } from "react-native-chart-kit";

import Styles from './Styles';

export default function Charts(){
    const chartConfig = {
    backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 0,
    backgroundGradientToOpacity: 0,
    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
    strokeWidth: 3, 
    barPercentage: 0.5,
    useShadowColorFromDataset: false,
    propsForBackgroundLines: {
        strokeDasharray: "",
        strokeOpacity: 0.0
    },

  };


return (
    <View>
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={[Styles.chart.card]}>
                <LineChart data={{
                                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
                                datasets: [
                                            {
                                                data: [
                                                    Math.random() * 100,
                                                    Math.random() * 100,
                                                    Math.random() * 100,
                                                    Math.random() * 100,
                                                    Math.random() * 100,
                                                    Math.random() * 100
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                }}
                                width={Dimensions.get("window").width}
                                height={300}
                                yAxisLabel={undefined}
                                yAxisInterval={undefined}
                                chartConfig={chartConfig}
                                withHorizontalLabels={false}
                                bezier
                                hidePointsAtIndex={[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
                                style={{
                                }}/>
            </View>
        </ScrollView> 
    </View>
    
);
}

Si es imposible llegar a ese resultado, existe alguna otra librería que permita una mayor edición del gráfico?
Gracias.

He encontrado la solución, se ajustó el chartConfig de esta manera:
const chartConfig = {
    backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 0,
    backgroundGradientToOpacity: 0,
    color: () => `rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)`, /* Evita la opacidad */
    strokeWidth: 3, 
    barPercentage: 0.5,
    useShadowColorFromDataset: false,
    propsForBackgroundLines: {
        strokeDasharray: "",
        strokeOpacity: 0.0
    },

    /* Ajusta el relleno el gráfico */
    fillShadowGradient: 'transparent',
    fillShadowGradientOpacity: 0,
    fillShadowGradientFromOffset: 0,
    fillShadowGradientTo: 'transparent',
    fillShadowGradientToOpacity: 0,

  };

Resultado:

